# Differences not being merged into master

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a feature branch, sprint12 that I am trying to merge into master.  Started a pull request but i ran into merge conflicts.  So Then I abandoned the pull request and checked out master and tried to merge manually so as to resolve the conflicts.

I'm not sure where things went wrong, but I'm now in a situation where if I try to merge from the sprint12 branch into master (in visual studio), it says 'already up todate', yet it wont build - which means all the changes from the sprint12 branch ARE NOT merged for some reason.

How can I cleanup this mess.  I want to get master to look like my sprint12 branch.  Also to note, if I start a new pull request for sprint12 into master, I see a message "There are no changes to merge between the selected branches."

Comment: In short, since your first merge resolution is botched, you'd have to either revert the merge (if the repo is shared ans someone might alreayd have pulled master since your bad pull request), or (if you're working alone here) reset master to just before the merge and redo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What resolved the issue for me was to pull in any discrepencies from master via a merge, then commit, and THEN commit my feature branch changes into master.
This effectively replaces master with the feature branch, which is more or less what I was after.

eg.

```
git checkout feature_branch
git merge -s ours --no-commit master
git commit          # add information to the template merge message
git checkout master
git merge feature_branch #fast-for­ward merge
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue a week ago. If you notice all the changes from sprint12 branch already present in master branch, I suggest you to add a comment line or any format change(just to trick a change detection) in sprint12 branch and raise a PR from sprint12 branch into master. This should trigger a new build and successful.